# Reintegrate to the branch (not the trunk) in Subversion (SVN)

Tags: svn, svn-reintegrate

I know there is the `--reintegrate` option in Subversion (SVN) 1.6 to merge a feature branch back to the trunk.

My workflow is a little more complex:

We have feature branches - we merge trunk to them often. But we don't put them back to trunk right away. Instead we create a release branch off the trunk, and merge feature branches to release branch. At this point we get a lot of tree conflicts (since lot of changes exist both in feature branch and the trunk).

Option `--reintegrate` must help in this scenario, but it looks like `--reintegrate` doesn't work when merging to the branch other than trunk. Is that true?

Comment: So looks like no reintegrate required: Was able to solve my problem after reading this: http://designbygravity.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/what-mother-never-told-you-about-svn-branching-and-merging/

Answer (score 4):

It's news to me that you can't use the `--reintegrate` option on any branch besides `trunk`. Subversion doesn't have *any* standard on naming or the placement of branches, so there's no way that `trunk` is special. To Subversion, `branches`, `trunk`, and `tags` are mere directories. These directories are only special to us because we said so.

The `--reintegrate` option has to do with the fact that if I merge from branch *A* to branch *B*, and then try to merge back from branch *B* to branch *A*, I might be attempting to merge stuff back to branch *A* that was initially in branch *A*. The `--reintegrate` option lets Subversion know that I am reversing the direction of my merge, and to not consider stuff in branch *B* that was really the result of merging from branch *A*.

Reintegration is an issue in any version control system that actually tracks merged changes. In any case, there's no reason why `--reintegrate` must involve a branch called `trunk`. Otherwise, there's no real need for the option. All Subversion has to do is see you're merging into a branch called `trunk` and realize it's probably a reintegration.

Comment: Yes, i was under same impression - reintegrate couldn't be restricted, but i never saw people reintegrate to other than trunk, and when i do reintegrate to the branch i get this: svn: '/svn/!svn/bc/364751/<module>/releases/<branch i reintegrate into>' path not found

Comment: So looks like reintegrate is not what i need. I need 2 feature branches merged to release branch(copy of trunk). So how do i let svn know to not consider stuff in branch R that was really the result of merging from branch T and get rid of all these tree conflicts?

Comment: So you go from Trunk->Feature_branch, then Trunk->Release_branch. Changes in Trunk are merged to Feature_branch. You also commit changes to Feature_branch. Finally, you want to merge Feature_branch to Release_branch. I'm not 100% sure that will work since the two branches are not directly related. Svn's merging is still a bit weak. You might be better off using the `--ignore-ancestory`. Subscribe to the [Subversion list](http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) and ask there. That list specializes in Subversion issues and probably has more expertise than available here.